# CSS :not for selector on the same level

Tags: css, sass

I have this html, sometimes `stars--done` is not there but I want to alter the CSS.

```
<div class="stars stars--done">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</div>
```

Currently I have this

```
.stars {
  &:hover {
    i {
      //do somehting
    }
  }
}
```

I only want to make the `<i>` do something if the parent *does not* match `.stars--done`

```
.stars {
  &:not('.stars--done'):hover {
    i {
      //do somehting
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `&:not(.stars--done):hover {`

Comment: @CBroe just post that as an answer. Was writing that but you commented already so I discarded my answer

Comment: @NenadVracar he doesn't want to hover the i but the div.starts, so it should be &:not(.stars--done):hover like CBroe said

Comment: @CBroe Damn you there quicker, If you post it as answer I will discard mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Doomenik your answer with `&:hover:not(.stars--done) {` was spot on. Having `:hover` at the start gives the functionality I want whereas having `:hover` after changes it.  If you resubmit your answer I will accept.

Comment: @bettercalldough I have, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont stringify the selector, this is not Jquery. Simply remove the ''.

```
.stars {
  &:not(.stars--done):hover {
    i {
      //do somehting
    }
  }
}
```

Ps you can also write:

```
.stars {
  &:hover:not(.stars--done) {
    i {
      //do somehting
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is actually a difference between the two stated above but to achieve what I wanted I used the second option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
.stars {
  &:not('.stars--done'):hover {
    i {
        …
```

This will compile to

```
.stars:not('.stars--done'):hover i { …
```

which is not what you want. Remove the quotes:

```
.stars {
  &:not(.stars--done):hover {
    i {
        …
```